# Determine virtual private gateway limit using api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to determine, programmatically using the AWS EC2 API, an account's virtual private gateway limit for a region? I know that the default limit is 5, but that an aws customer can increase this if they want. I am building a product which will create a virtual private gateway (vgw) in a client's AWS account and I want to know, before attempting to create the vgw, if the client has room for one more. I don't want to tell a client by default that they have reached the vgw limit of 5 if they are allowed to use more.

The method 'DescribeAccountAttributes' only includes the following fields

```
{ AccountAttributes: 
   [ { AttributeName: 'supported-platforms',
       AttributeValues: [ { AttributeValue: 'VPC' } ] },
     { AttributeName: 'vpc-max-security-groups-per-interface',
       AttributeValues: [ { AttributeValue: '5' } ] },
     { AttributeName: 'max-elastic-ips',
       AttributeValues: [ { AttributeValue: '5' } ] },
     { AttributeName: 'max-instances',
       AttributeValues: [ { AttributeValue: '20' } ] },
     { AttributeName: 'vpc-max-elastic-ips',
       AttributeValues: [ { AttributeValue: '5' } ] },
     { AttributeName: 'default-vpc',
       AttributeValues: [ { AttributeValue: 'vpc-********' } ] } ] }
```

and the method 'DescribeVpnGateways' just returns an array of the current gateways without specifying any limits on them.

Any ideas?